# How to extract elements by tagName from XML URL using Selenium Python

Tags: python, xml, selenium, selenium-webdriver, elementtree

I'm trying to find elements by tag name like Titles from this XML URL http://www.rssmix.com/u/8287461/rss.xml but unable it's not working please help

It is just printing a blank page and nothing else

```
browser.get("http://www.rssmix.com/u/8287461/rss.xml")
time.sleep(10)
title = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name('title')
description = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name('description')
link = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name('link')
for p_title, p_description, p_links in zip(title, description, link):
    title_s = p_title.text
    description_s = p_description.text
    link_s = p_links.text
    print (title_s + "\t"  + description_s +  "\t"  + link_s + "\n")
```

Comment: You are opening XML document, that document by itself has no `title`, or any other tag, so how you see it (as well as all HTML elements) depends on the **viewer** browser uses to display such document.
So what you are doing is quite meaningless. What are you trying to achieve? Test browser's XML viewer? or do something with that XML (e.g. test it or parse it)? or something else?

Comment: nope in the xml there are <Title> tags and I want to extract them all is that not possible

Comment: lol, do you understand the difference between xml and html?

Comment: For one thing Selenium does not parse XML for you, it interacts with HTML

Comment: so how do I do please let me know..  how I can extract titles descriptions and links

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912434/how-do-i-parse-xml-in-python

Comment: Recommend to use http client python package to fetch this XML to local 
 or xml string in memory, then use XML parse package, like BeautifulSoup to find things from local xml or xml string in memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your question as you want to extract **tags** from a **XML URL** you can use:

- The [`fromstring()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.fromstring) method and
- The [`iter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.iter) method

from *Python's* [**xml.etree.ElementTree — The ElementTree XML API**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) along with *Selenium* as follows:

- Code Block:

  ```
  # -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
  from selenium import webdriver
  import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
  driver=webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("http://www.rssmix.com/u/8287461/rss.xml")
  root = ET.fromstring(driver.page_source)
  print("Titles are : ")
  for neighbor1 in root.iter('title'):
      print(neighbor1.text)
  print("Descriptions are : ")
  for neighbor2 in root.iter('description'):
      print(neighbor2.text)
  print("Links are : ")
  for neighbor3 in root.iter('link'):
      print(neighbor3.text)
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Titles are : 
  RSSMix.com Mix ID 8287461
  Paul Pierce and Baron Davis Say Warriors Are Top 5 Team Ever, Talk NBA Finals
  ASAP Rocky and Skepta's Worlds Collide in "Praise the Lord (Da Shine)" Video
  Scott Pruitt Might Just Be the Cheapest Crook of the Bunch
  The Complete Off-White x Nike Price Guide
  Pennsylvania Middle Schoolers Given Bulletproof Shields to Prepare for High-School
  J. Prince Claims Kanye Contacted Him to Squash the Drake vs. Pusha-T Beef
  Best Look at Black Levi's x Air Jordan 4s
  Kendall Jenner Seen Making Out with Bella Hadid's 18-Year-Old Brother
  How to Have an Ingrown Hair-Free Summer
  Diane Keaton Is Renovating Yet Another Home
  The Chic Way To Style Your Bed On The Floor
  21 Plant-Filled Instagrams That Will Turn Your Black Thumb Green
  The Summer Paint Trends We're Living For
  Amazon Now Has All Your Favorite Hard-to-Find Skincare Products
  The Best Place to Buy Tiny Homes? Amazon
  Earn $10,000 Simply By Moving to This State
  15 Bathroom Essentials Every Minimalist Deserves
  Pink Sofas Are Our Favorite Living Room Eye Candy
  'Chlorophyll' Comes to the Nike Air Max Speed Turf
  # many more ...
  Descriptions are : 
  This feed was created by mixing existing feeds from various sources.
  "I'm a basketball historian, so when I look at this team, this team can play with any team in NBA history," Paul Pierce tells Complex News. "It's probably one of the top five teams ever."
  ASAP Rocky's Skepta-assisted 'Testing' standout gets a gritty Dexter Navy-directed music video that brings together the worlds of New York City and London.
  <p>He's the subject of a dozen probes. The newest scandal involves Chick-fil-A.</p>
  What's the current market value of every Virgil Abloh Nike and Jordan Off-White collaboration?
  8th graders at the St. Cornelius School in Chadds Ford, Pennsylvania were gifted bulletproof shields for their backpacks.
  J Prince reiterates his claims that Drake was ready to "destroy" Pusha's career with a devastating diss track before Kanye West stepped in.
  Levi's and Jordan Brand team up for a black-based version of their Air Jordan 4 collaboration.
  Despite reports that Jenner has been dating Ben Simmons for weeks, the model was spotted cuddling and kissing 18-year-old Anwar Hadid following the CFDA awards.
  It's the season of sunshine, swimsuits, and cocktails. But what about hair removal? Kind of the worst part of summer, right? Good thing we've put together your handy guide on how to treat and prevent ingrown hairs.
  Peek inside the Tucson, Arizona home that Diane Keaton just bought for $1.5 million. The design-loving actress actually flips a lot of homes in her free time, and we can't wait to see what she does with this one.
  Bedframes are bulky and expensive—so if you need to ditch yours in favor of something more low maintenance, we've got you covered. Here are our favorite hacks for styling your bed on the floor, whether you're leaning boho or prefer minimalism.
  Discover the best, inspiring plant-filled Instagrams to follow. From plant photography to houseplants in stunning interiors and tips to keeping your green guys alive, these Instagram accounts have it all. For more plant guides, visit domino.
  Discover the colors that are inspiring team Domino, and learn how to bring them into your home. From citron to the vibrant pinks, here are all the wall paints we can't get enough of this summer.
  At this point, is there nothing Amazon can't do? From plants to their own furniture line to luxury skincare—and now this: a new, dermatologist-approved vertical making skincare easier to shop for than ever.
  Looking to downsize? Amazon's got you covered. The retailer has a slew of tiny homes on the market—and one in particular is catching our eye. Here's how to get in on the small space living trend in a super accessible way.
  Working remotely, and looking for a place to relocate to? Vermont just announced its Remote Worker Grant program, which will give out of state remote workers $10,000 to relocate. Get all the details here.
  Looking to make your bathroom feel more like a spa? These are our picks for the best accessories for a design-forward bathroom. For more decor ideas and inspiration, head to Domino.
  Love statement seating as much as we do? We are seeing dreamy pink couches all over the internet—and, we have to admit, we are obsessed. Take it from these eight living rooms, your home deserves a bold splash of pink every now and again.
  # many more ...
  Links are : 
  http://www.rssmix.com/
  https://www.complex.com/sports/2018/06/paul-pierce-baron-davis-say-warriors-are-top-5-team-ever
  https://www.complex.com/music/2018/06/asap-rocky-skepta-praise-the-lord-da-shine-video
  https://www.esquire.com/news-politics/politics/a21087456/scott-pruitt-chick-fil-a-wife/
  https://www.complex.com/sneakers/2018/06/virgil-abloh-off-white-nike-jordan-resale-price-guide/
  https://www.complex.com/life/2018/06/pennsylvania-middle-school-bulletproof-shields-given-to-students-to-prepare-high-school
  https://www.complex.com/music/2018/06/j-prince-claims-kanye-west-called-to-squash-drake-pusha-t-beef
  https://www.complex.com/sneakers/2018/06/levis-air-jordan-4-iv-black-release-date-ao2571-001
  https://www.complex.com/pop-culture/2018/06/kendall-jenner-seen-making-out-with-bella-hadids-18-year-old-brother
  https://domino.com/how-to-treat-ingrown-hairs
  https://domino.com/diane-keaton-tucson-arizona-home
  https://domino.com/bed-on-floor-hacks
  https://domino.com/best-plant-photography-instagram-accounts-to-follow
  https://domino.com/summer-paint-trends
  https://domino.com/amazon-professional-skin-care-section
  https://domino.com/amazon-tiny-home-for-sale-2018
  https://domino.com/vermont-remote-worker-grant-program
  https://domino.com/bathroom-accessories-picks
  https://domino.com/pink-couch
  # many more ...
  ```